# Как привести ответ от БД в нормальный вид

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Только начинаю изучать Laravel и никогда не сталкивался с её PDO.Сильно не пинайте

Кидаю запрос к БД

```
$tmp = DB::table('case')->where ('id' ,'=', $key)->get();
```

После чего смотрю, что получил

```
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($tmp);
echo "</pre>";
```

> object(Illuminate\Support\Collection)#203 (1) {
>   ["items":protected]=>   array(0) {   } }
>
> object(Illuminate\Support\Collection)#204 (1) {
>   ["items":protected]=>   array(0) {   } }
>
> object(Illuminate\Support\Collection)#202 (1) {
>   ["items":protected]=>   array(1) {
>       [0]=>
>       object(stdClass)#198 (11) {
>         ["id"]=>
>         int(36)
>         ["one_worker_id"]=>
>         int(0)
>         ["status"]=>
>         string(3) "off"
>         ["two_worker_id"]=>
>         int(0)
>         ["location"]=>
>         string(26) "Муром, Артёма 4"
>         ["lng"]=>
>         string(17) "42.03792083740245"
>         ["lat"]=>
>         string(17) "55.57619655127353"
>         ["progress"]=>
>         float(250.07)
>         ["size"]=>
>         float(250)
>         ["date"]=>
>         string(19) "2018-05-28 16:44:04"
>         ["step"]=>
>         string(4) "0.25"
>       }   } }

что означают первые две коллекции под номерами 203 и 204?

Раньше я мог обращаться вот так к ответу - `$tmp[0]->lat` и было всё хорошо, а сейчас ошибка - `Undefined offset: 0`

Как по правильному нужно обращаться к нужному элемента из полученного ответа?

Comment: у вас надо спрашивать, что они обозначают. видимо запрос выполняется в цикле, и первые две итерации возвращают пустой результат.

Comment: @teran нет, не в цикле

Comment: не убедили, но для проверки, все же можете добавить `echo "hello world"` после `var_dump`. у вас тут явно виден вывод трех объектов, они никак не объединены сами по себе. так что это разные вардампы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по ошибке первые два массива пустые,поэтому

```
    $tmp[2]->lat
```